# Boxed Style not creating a box

Tags: list, list-view

I created a list which has several columns (12 in total). I originally had shaded style but then changed to boxed style, however the actual list is not in box format. I cleared my cache and getting the same issue, it still looks like a database. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Can I not have that many columns? I tried with labels and without labels.

I created a new list with only 2 columns, but I'm having the same issue where it does not change to box style. Any clues why I might be running into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SharePoint Online / Office 365 with the "Modern UI", then the View Styles are ignored.

Comment: @JasmineGreene Pls upvote/mark as answer. It will help someone in need for future searches..